# Is math in CSS' calc faster than math in JS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

For example, if I want to update a CSS value at 60fps, would it be faster to do something like `setCSS(i * 10 + 'px')` in JS or something like  in css`property: calc(10px * var(--i))`?

Comment: The difference is probably so negligible, that any benefit of finding the answer is likely lost by the amount of time it took for you to write this question. Because you mentioned 60fps, it sounds like you have a not-very performant animation you are concerned with. If that's that case, please look at using the css `translate` properties. Certain things do not animate well -- such as height, width, any positioning using `absolute` values (top, left, right, bottom), among others.

Comment: What is `setCSS()`?

Comment: @isherwood loops like OP is just using setCSS as a theoretical js function for the example

Comment: you should use `requestAnimationFrame` with timing logic to get smooth animations at 60 fps. here's you a decorator for use with react components to perform smooth animations, and yes, you can run multiple at once and it won't choke. https://gist.github.com/r3wt/172f61842c5d2a98cc3e49b336b6e988 this assumes you know start and end position of property, if you don't you could rework it to be indeterminate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are CSS animations faster than JS animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782640/are-css-animations-faster-than-js-animations)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think speed is the issue that you would use to determine which to use. Any client that supports `calc()` is going to be fast and it's really implementation-specific as to how fast.

The reason to choose one over the other isn't speed, it's flexibility and your use case. `calc()` limits you to hard-coded values and that is perfect for some cases, while JavaScript allows you to reference values. Sure CSS variables are coming, but they are not here yet and even when they get here, having the full power of the JS language and the full DOM API weighs heavily.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  By how much? Imperceptible amounts in most cases, which is why the answer on which to use isn't based on speed. Hence, my very short answer. Sorry it was too long for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends heavily on your DOM tree and markup rather than JS vs. CSS. 
If your element which you are planning to change does have child elements the cost of changes will be high.

> If you change a “layout” property, so that’s one that changes an element’s geometry, like its width, height, or its position with left or top, the browser will have to check all the other elements and “reflow” the page. Any affected areas will need to be repainted, and the final painted elements will need to be composited back together.

More reading about web page rendering can be found on https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

There are also information and some tests about css cals with variables vs js
https://lisilinhart.info/posts/css-variables-performance/